# AttirbuteError in class(turtle class inheritance)

Tags: python, class, python-turtle

```
class Turtle_new(turtle.Turtle):
  def __init__(self):
    self.walks = 10000

  def go(self):
    r1 = random.randint(0,90)
    r2 = random.randint(270,360)
    if random.randint(0,1): 
      self.setheading(r1)
    else:
      self.setheading(r2)
    self.pensize(3)
    self.speed('fast')
    r4 = random.randint(0, 255)
```

> **self.setheading(r1)**.

The Attirbute Error occurs in line 9.

> ***'Turtle_new' object has no attribute '_orient'***

This is the error. I have changed "self.setheading" to "super()" but the error occurs. Also same error occurs in *self.speed('fast)*    changed "_orient" to "_screen".
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure `Turtle.__init__` is called so that your instance is initialized properly. Unlike some languages, the parent initializer is not called automatically; you have to be explicit.

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Turtle_new(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, kwargs):
         super().__init__(**kwargs)
         self.walks = 10000

    ...
```

`Turtle.__init__` (indirectly) initializes `self._orient`. Exactly how isn't really relevant to this answer; you can explore [the `turtle` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/turtle.py) if you are curious.